# theorem on power series $\log(z^2-iz+2)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, taylor-expansion

I know how to solve this question.. but dont know using the theorem 
[image]

I know how to find radius of convergence as **the wolframalpha says no poles for the log function, how to find then minimum distance ?**

Comment: What's the theorem? The radius of convergence is the distance from the center of expansion to the nearest singularity.

Comment: What do you mean "without this theorem how to use this theorem"

Comment: please help ... yes @MPW

Comment: You are told the center of expansion is $z_0=0$. So for each function, list the singularities and find the distance from $0$ to each of these singularities. The smallest of these is the radius. Do you know how to find the distance between two complex numbers?

Comment: yes i know how to find distance thank you :)

Comment: Poles aren’t the only kind of singularity. So you can’t think of any point where $\log z$ misbehaves?